# How can I pull in properties of a user based on their email address?

Tags: infopath, web-services, user-profile-service

EDIT: Another way of asking this same question, I guess, is: is there an out of the box web service to which I can pass an email address as a parameter, and get other properties for that user back as a result?

---

So, I have used this neat trick to pull in the current user information:
[InfoPath - Get the current user without writing code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx?from=ClayCobb)

Now, I have a different scenario that I need to implement.
I have a form that will be pre-populated with the user's email address, and I want to access other properties of their profile using the email address as the key.

The GetUserProfileByName web service seems to be the right one to use, but I want to be able to pass it a value from the form and return the profile information I need (in this case, the user's manager).

Comment: You can use Search to do that, too. Execute a People search with the email address and return the Account.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetUserProfileByName` requires that you pass it the `AccountName` instead of an email address.  One option might be to pre-populate the people picker as you are wanting to do, and then call `GetUserProfileByName` via a rule and pass it the `AccountId` property that is stored within the people picker.  Here's [another link](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=178) that you might find useful while doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll find these articles useful - 
[InfoPath - Get the current user without writing code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2007/04/05/InfoPath-_2D00_-Get-the-current-user-without-writing-code.aspx)

[InfoPath 2010 Best Practice Querying User Profile Web Service](http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2013/02/24/infopath-2010-best-practice-querying-user-profile-web-service/)